# Convert MongoDB query to spring data mongo template

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I need to convert the below Query to spring data mongo template. i have looked at many example but none have setunion with and array inside

```
{​​​​​​​
           $project: {​​​​​​​
               "datastreamId": 1,
               "datastreamName": 1,
               "deviceId":  1,
               "searchTags": {​​​​​​​ $arrayElemAt: [ "$searchTags", 0 ] }​​​​​​​,
               "datastreamPos":  {​​​​​​​$arrayElemAt:[{​​​​​​​$split: ["$datastreamId" , "_"]}​​​​​​​, 1]}​​​​​​​,
               "destId": "$destNode.id",
               "dataBucketId": "$dataBucketNode.id",
               "assetId": "$assetNode.id",
               "hierarchy": {​​​​​​​ $setUnion: [ "$hierarchy", [{​​​​​​​id: "$datastreamId", name: "$datastreamName", levelType: "Channel", level:6}​​​​​​​] ] }​​​​​​​
           }​​​​​​​
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ConcatArrays to have an array inside SetUnion like this

```
Document arrayDocument = new Document();
arrayDocument.put("id", "$datastreamId");
arrayDocument.put("name", "$datastreamName");
arrayDocument.put("levelType", "Channel");
arrayDocument.put("level", 6);

ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays array = ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf(Collections.singletonList(arrayDocument));
SetOperators.SetUnion setUnion = SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet("hierarchy").union(array);
```

Now use this setUnion inside Projection.

Note: As we are providing List with a single element only inside `$concatArrays`, it will convert it into an array that you want.